# How to use Terminal to delete all .svn folders recursively?

Tags: macos, svn, terminal.app

What command can I type into the Terminal so that I can delete all `.svn` folders within a folder (and from all subdirectories) but not delete anything else?

Comment: Maybe you could just `svn export path/to/repo path/to/export/to` instead...

Comment: A note on `svn export` is that is doesn't copy across files that are not part of svn. For example, I wanted to do this for an iOS application that uses Cocoa Pods where we do not commit the Pods folder. This was then skipped from the output. I ended up using something similar to Rich's answer for what I wanted.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
cd to/dir/where/you/want/to/start
find . -type d -name '.svn' -print -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

- Use find, which does recursion
- in the current directory .
- filetype is
  directory
- filename is .svn
- print what matched up to this point (the .svn dirs)
- exec the command `rm -rf (thing found from find)`. the {} is a placeholder for the
  entity found
- the ; tells find that the command for exec is done.
  Since the shell also has an idea of what ; is, you need to escape it
  with \ so that the shell doesn't do anything special with it, and just passes to find

Comment: Good solution. While `find` has `-delete` it won't delete non-empty directories. This approach is cleaner than e.g. starting to match parts of the whole path of files.

Comment: I'd recommend running it without the `-exec rm -rf {} \;` the first time to make sure it's only finding what you want it to. I've never had an issue where I've accidentally deleting the wrong thing with it, because I always check first.

Comment: @Rob good point, i usually do -exec echo rm -rf {} \; then remove the echo.

Comment: Another option if there are not too many would be to confirm deletion of each file with `-exec rm -ri {} \;`

Comment: `-exec rm -rf {} +` is probably many times as fast, because it doesn’t have to launch too many `rm` instances. Instead, it packs the maximum amount of arguments (directories to remove in this case) in one call. This is possible because `rm` accepts multiple arguments.

Comment: Thank youuuu!!! So happy for this. And thanks for the explanation of what the command does at each step.

Comment: Thanks for this command and its simple explanation. However, in some instances, i get "Operation not permitted". Is there a way to force the deletion still? I am trying to clean a backup drive, and those files add so much time to the backup process otherwise. Thanks in advance!